# C# TCP Async EndReceive() throws InvalidOperationException ONLY on Windows XP 32-bit

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous

I have a simple C# Async Client using a .NET socket that waits for timed messages from a local Java server used for automating commands. The messages come in asynchronously and is written to a ring buffer. This implementation seems to work fine on Windows Vista/7/8 and OSX, but will randomly throw this exception while it's receiving a message from the local Java server:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: EndReceive can only be called once for each asynchronous operation.
>       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult, SocketError& errorCode)
>       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>       at SocketTest.Controller.RecvAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
>       at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr userToken)
>       ...

I've looked online for this error, but have found nothing really helpful. This is the code where it seems to break:

```
/// <summary>
/// Callback to receive socket data
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ar">AsyncResult to pass to End</param>
private void RecvAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    // The exception will randomly happen on this call
    int bytes = _socket.EndReceive(_recvAsyncResult);

    // check for connection closed
    if (bytes == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    _ringBuffer.Write(_buffer, 0, bytes);

    // Checks buffer
    CheckBuffer();

    _recvAsyncResult = _sock.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, RecvAsyncCallback, null);
}
```

The error doesn't happen on any particular moment except in the middle of receiving a message. The message itself can be any length for this to happen, and the exception can happen right away, or sometimes even up to a minute of perfect communication.

I'm pretty new with sockets and network communication, and I feel I might be missing something here. I've tested on at least 8 different computers, and the only similarity with the computers that throw this exception is that their OS is Windows XP 32-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to follow [the convention shown here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7wtt64b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You are passing in an `IAsyncResult` to `Socket.BeginReceive` that represents a different point in the context or an entirely different context.

Make sure that in your callback you are using the parameter that is passed in when you call `EndReceive`.

Windows XP may have a bug fix in it, depending on your service pack and what other things you have installed, that catches a context sharing scenario or perhaps it has a bug introduced which does not correctly manage the contexts. It's hard to tell if it's an environment issue or not, without extensive testing.

Comment: Just tested, seems to be working fine now, thank you!
It's weird that it only happens on WinXP though, I'll post back if I find out anything more.

Comment: @JamesFarmer I ran a test on a Windows XP development box and could not reproduce the issue with the latest updates. That tells me it may have been a bug in an older version of the framework or something of that sort.